# How to do arithmetic operation in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I am performing the following in the makefile to measure the time taken in doing some operation:-

```
START=$(shell date +%s) <br>
@if [ -s mfill.mapi.diff ]; then echo "difference exist between GOLDEN map file and test map file, see mfill.map.diff" ; fi <br>
END=$(shell date +%s) <br>
DIFF_SUB=$(shell echo $(END)\-$(START) | bc) <br>
@echo "It took ${DIFF_SUB} seconds"
```

It results in following output :-

> START=1309941257 
>   END=1309941268 
>   DIFF_SUB=  
>   It took  seconds

Could you guys suggest where i did wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926063/arithmetic-in-a-makefile

Comment: @Fredrik: I am too lazy to not saw that post. I went through that post and that didn't work for me.

Comment: @amitesh - If you format code as code (rather than quote) you'll get syntax highlighting as a bonus.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - Could you please share the procedure of how to do that?

Comment: @amitesh - You can either indent the whole code block (hitting Ctrl+K or copying it already indented) or just use the **{}** toolbar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be using curly braces for Makefile variables: $(END) not ${END}

You want subtraction but you used a '*'.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat Makefile 
START=3
END=5
DIFF_SUB=$(shell echo $(END)-$(START) | bc)
test:
    @echo it took $(DIFF_SUB) seconds
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make
it took 2 seconds
```

If you're doing these inside the target, use your curly braces but double $s: `$${DIFF_SUB}`

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat Makefile 
START=3
END=5
DIFF_SUB=$(shell echo $(END)-$(START) | bc)
test:
    @echo it took $(DIFF_SUB) seconds
test2:
    @START=3 && \
    echo HELLO && \
    END=7 && \
    DIFF_SUB=$$(($$END - $$START)) && \
    echo it took $${DIFF_SUB} seconds
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make test test2
it took 2 seconds
HELLO
it took 4 seconds
```

Comment: works for me, did you change all the curly braces? did you change the asterisk to a minus sign? you've still got curly braces around DIFF_SUB.

Comment: I am doing the above operation inside the target. I think it is not creating problem. @ jcomeau_ictx : I did that and edited above but it is not working.

Comment: see edited answer. you're still showing curly braces around DIFF_SUB.

Comment: wait, if you're doing that inside the target, it's a different story altogether. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: see revised answer. you're going to run into trouble mixing Make constructs with Bash constructs; use one or the other.

Comment: Why you add "&& \" in the end of statements?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1175/discussion-between-amitesh-and-jcomeau-ictx)

Comment: because each line of Bash runs in its own context; the values don't carry on to the next line, it has to be all on one line.

Comment: Could you please insert one statement such as "echo HELLO" between "START" and "END" and let it work for me?