# How to properly add two numbers in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I would like to know which solution is better to add two numbers in a Makefile. In my case I will would use the function `add` as shown below:

```
result = $(call add, 34, 56)
$(error $(result))
```

Solution 1:

```
add    = $(shell echo $$(( $(1) + $(2) )))
```

Solution 2:

```
add    = $(shell perl -e 'print $1 + $2')
```

Solution 3:

```
add    = $(shell echo '$1 + $2' | bc | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Solution 4:

```
16 := x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
_input_int := $(foreach a,$(16),$(foreach b,$(16),$(foreach c,$(16),$(16)))))

_decode = $(words $1)
_encode = $(wordlist 1,$1,$(_input_int))
_plus = $1 $2
_max = $(subst xx,x,$(join $1,$2))

_push = $(eval stack := $$1 $(stack))
_pop = $(word 1,$(stack))$(eval stack := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(stack)),$(stack)))
_pope = $(call _encode,$(call _pop))
_pushd = $(call _push,$(call _decode,$1))

calculate=$(eval stack:=)$(foreach t,$1,$(call handle,$t))$(stack)
handle   =$(call _pushd,                                          \
            $(if $(filter +,$1),                                  \
              $(call _plus,$(call _pope),$(call _pope)),          \
                $(call _encode,$1)))

add     = $(strip $(foreach v,$(2), $(call calculate, $v $(1) +)))
```

I admit the solution 4 is ridiculous but it is the only one that does not depend on an external tool such as `bash`, `perl` or `bc`.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion is a POSIX shell feature, thus you don't have to rely specifically on `bash` for solution 1,  any `sh` should work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715839/1819452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/), it provides integer arithmetic functions.

Comment: This library is fantastic !