# Boolean circuit using basic arithmetic?

Tags: shell, math, gnu-make

According to [How do I perform arithmetic in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926063), we can perform basic arithmetic through the Posix shell in a GNUmakefile (see [Dominic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15978322/608639)).

I got really excited because I have suffered lack of logical operators in the past. So I coded up the following test on OS X:

```
GCC42_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "^gcc version (4.[2-9]|[5-9])")
IS_DARWIN = $(shell uname -s | $(EGREP) -i -c "darwin")
CLANG_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -i -c "clang")

# Below, we are building a boolean circuit that says "Darwin && (GCC 4.2 or above || Clang)"
SUPPORTS_MULTIARCH = $$($(IS_DARWIN) * $$($(GCC42_OR_LATER) + $(CLANG_COMPILER)))

ifneq ($(SUPPORTS_MULTIARCH),0)
CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
else
CXXFLAGS += -march=native
endif
```

A run on OS X showed `-arch x86_64 -arch i386`, and that was expected.

I then added a `IS_DARWIN=0` before the math, which should have driven everything low. But it did not, and I got `-arch x86_64 -arch i386` again.

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: The support for `$((..))` is a shell feature not a make one. Note that your linked answer is doing that in a recipe line. So you need to involve the shell in your snippet to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, to have `$$(())` arithmetic work, you need to involve the shell <del>and that shell needs to be bash.</del> (EDIT: Apparently it doesn't, and any POSIX shell will work, even something as minimal as dash)

<del>So first off, add this to the top of your `Makefile`:

    SHELL=/bin/bash</del>

Then, the line you were playing with should read:

```
# Below, we are building a boolean circuit that says "Darwin && (GCC 4.2 or above || Clang)"
SUPPORTS_MULTIARCH = $(shell echo $$(( $(IS_DARWIN) * ( $(GCC42_OR_LATER) + $(CLANG_COMPILER) ) )) )
```

I've added extra spaces in that line to show clearly what's matching with what. Feel free to delete them, though they do no harm.

Inside the double-paren-arithmetic group, you don't need `$$((` to start an arithmetic subgroup; just use ordinary parentheses.

Comment: modern `ksh`s also support `$(( math ))` operations. Good luck to all!

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the excitement got the best of me, and I rushed to cut-in the logic.

Comment: @Daniel - are you certain about *"... and that shell needs to be bash..."*. I believe the comments say a Posix shell is the minimum requirements. Your answer works fine in my setup, including tests on OS X, Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenBSD and FreeBSD. Maybe I should do some testing just in case.

Comment: You know, you're right. I don't think the shell needs to be bash after all - I was basing that on what the linked answer said. So you can delete the SHELL= line